# Selecting value from the Dropdown using selenium web-driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a small doubt over here on selecting one of the value from the drop down using selenium . When i generated a code using selenium-IDE it gave me a set of codes for selecting from the drop-down .
Code is as follows-->

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.search")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='project-add-table']/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select"))).selectByVisibleText("Test");
```

So can anybody tell what is the use of that second line of code ?After clicking to the dropdown why cant we directly select the required element?

HTML -->

```html
<td class="environmentTd" required="">
   <div class="ui fluid search dropdown env selection">
      <select>
         <option value="SB">Sandbox</option>
         <option value="DEV">Development</option>
         <option value="QA">Test</option>
         <option value="PROD">Production</option>
         <option value="PP">Pre Production</option>
         <option value="UAT">UAT</option>
         <option value="DR">DR</option>
      </select>
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i><input class="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0">
      <div class="text">Sandbox</div>
      <div class="menu transition hidden" tabindex="-1">
         <div class="item active selected" data-value="SB">Sandbox</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="DEV">Development</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="QA">Test</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="PROD">Production</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="PP">Pre Production</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="UAT">UAT</div>
         <div class="item" data-value="DR">DR</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: only third line of code is enough to select the value from dropdown. may be, first two lines are not related to dropdown selection.

Comment: Not it wont work with 3rd line alone .It gives exception .Its not able to find the element

Comment: is it working without second line of code?

Comment: Nope .Its not able to

Comment: Even i feel just 3rd like will be enough to select value from dropdown.

Comment: Nope because until we select the drop down button its not vissible

Comment: @AkshayKrishna Can you add the html? Seems the dropdown is not a conventional select element.

Comment: when are you able to see select node , is it after execution of 1st or 2nd line? or is it visible all the time

Comment: Not vissible all the time , On first click itself its vissible ..But then if i execute directly third line it wont click .It requires 2nd line to be executed before

Comment: If possible please post the website link here

Comment: sorry its not yet published it's deployed in  internal server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your select tag is visible in DOM without you clicking the dropdown, just use the third line

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select")));
select.selectByValue("QA");
```

Otherwise, click on the dropdown which will probably generate the `DIV` with class

```
class="menu transition hidden"
```

and then you can use the `select` line.

Answer (score 1):

U don't really need to click on dropdown. U need to find dropdown as WebElement, convert it to SelectElement and use it's class method to select option.

I assume, that in provided code you click on dropdown, then click on opened fields with options. But I think it's a lot of unnecessary actions. Unless you have any scripts, triggered by that clicks, which must be tested.

Answer (score -1):

From your description it sounds like the `SELECT` element isn't visible until the 2nd click happens. It's also possible that the 2nd click creates the `SELECT` element via Javascript. You could investigate this by using the Chrome devtools and search for the `SELECT` element before the 2nd click happens. See if it exists or maybe exists but is not visible. Then click on the 2nd element and see how the HTML changes. Without access to the site, that's about as good an explanation as we can provide. It's not something I would worry about. It's just the way the site is designed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18546710)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Sure it does. Did you read the question? There are two question marks in the question and this answer addresses both of them.

Comment: it does address them. i would expect a straightforward answer looks like "the use of that second line of code is ..." and " After clicking to the dropdown we cant we directly select the required element because ..."

Comment: So first you stated, `This does not provide an answer to the question.` Now you are stating, `it does address them.` So which is it? You seem to be confused.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108672/difference-between-addressing-and-answering-a-question

Comment: I will veto @GillesGouaillardet decision as : 1) Question heading is clear `Selecting value from the Dropdown using selenium web-driver` 2) HTML is provided 3) Code trials are provided 4) OP's question is clear `what is the use of that second line of code?` 5)While your answer mentions **also possible**, **could investigate**, **search for**, **See if it exists**, **maybe exists**, **not something I would worry**. IMHO, on `Stackoverflow` we are looking for `well researched` and `optimized` **`Good Answers`**.

Comment: This veto looks like a vet !

Comment: @DebanjanB 1) you need to look up what veto means because it doesn't mean what you think it means. 2) The question heading, as you call it, is not a question. A question in English ends in a `?` so why don't you talk to OP about how to properly form a question. It's not even a complete sentence so you can talk to him about that also since you are an English expert

Comment: @DebanjanB 3) There's no link to the site and none of the HTML provided addresses why a click is required to expose the `SELECT`. Because of that no one can definitively state why the 2nd line click is required. I explained the two reasons this is necessary, either it was hidden and is exposed by the click or it was created via JS by the click. If OP was still curious, he could investigate using my instructions which case was true.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet it's interesting to me that both of you are harping on my answer when none of the other answers actually answer the question and are in direct contradiction to OP's comments.

Comment: @JeffC you clearly misunderstand how Stack Overflow works. Your post ended up in the "Low Quality Posts" queue and i was given the option to review it. I initially judged it was suitable as a comment instead of an answer, so i recommended it for deletion. Per your comment, i gave it a second review, and i still believe it does **not answer** the question, so i kept my initial review. I did not read other answers and i won't unless they end up in my review queue. Are there incorrect and/or non suitable answers there ? maybe, but that is not the point.

Comment: @JeffC If you see incorrect answers, then downvote them. If you are unhappy with my recommendation, then flag it and ask a moderator to have a look at it. The fact you got zero upvote, no acceptance from the OP and two recommendations for deletion should tell you this post does not meet the standards of Stack Overflow. I might add you should consider deleting it, and post a crystal clear answer that will be hopefully well received and accepted.